# How can I define values from outside my script?

Tags: environment-variables, nsis

I'd like to pass some variables into my `.nsi` script. Either from the environment or the command line, how do I do this?

I found a [section in the documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.3) that suggests I can use the syntax `$%envVarName%` to use environment variables in my script, but this doesn't seem to work, when I have

```
File "/oname=$pluginsdir\inst.msi" "$%VERSION%-Installer-64bit.msi"
```

I get the error

```
File: "$%VERSION%-Installer-64bit.msi" -> no files found.
```

`$VERSION` is in my environment.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with trying to read environment variables, or some other way of passing values into my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$%VERSION%` should work if you used `set VERSION=1.2.3.4`

Or you can create defines: `makensis -DVERSION=1.2.3.4 myscript.nsi` and `File: "${VERSION}-Installer-64bit.msi"`